# Skip rows with non-BMP characters (emojis) when using LOAD DATA INFILE with REPLACE option?

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8

Emoji characters are messing up a loading system we built and I'm looking for a simple short-term solution.

Its a Java loading program that uses JDBC to execute MySQL commands with this structure:

```
LOAD DATA
  LOCAL INFILE `filepath` 
  REPLACE INTO TABLE `SOME_TABLE`
  CHARACTER SET utf8
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\'' ESCAPED BY ''
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(`col1`,...,`coln`)
```

SOME_TABLE has `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`.

We are running MySQL 5.6.22.

Its been working great for years, but recently the files that we load started having occasional non-BMP characters (that happen to be emojis) and the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ... command throws exceptions like:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9D\x93\x9C' for column 'fieldm' at row 3004
```

I understand that the long-term solution is we need to move the table to `CHARSET=utf8mb4`. However, the tables are huge at this point and conversion will not be easy.  There are also `VARCHAR(255)` fields indexed, and these need to be converted to `VARCHAR(191)` [to fit under max key length 767], or we need to go to DYNAMIC row format and set `innodb_large_prefix=true`.

We are looking for a short-term solution until we get to a point where we have time and resources to migrate to utfmb4.

It would be OK, in the short term, to simply discard the rows with non-BMP (emoji) characters.  But, `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE filepath REPLACE ...` will not skip the bad rows, it fails the entire file.

At this point, it looks like we will need to write some filtering in Java to remove the non-BMP (emoji) rows before calling `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE filepath REPLACE ...`. But, I am thinking that there must be some way to do this in MySQL without having to introduce that kind of pre-filter.

Does anybody have any ideas for a simple way to get MySQL to simply skip the rows that have non-BMP (emoji) data?

***** UPDATE  *****
It looks like using CONVERT might be the solution for short term.  Doing this replaces the Emoji with '????' in col4.

```
LOAD DATA
  LOCAL INFILE `filepath` 
  REPLACE INTO TABLE `SOME_TABLE`
  CHARACTER SET utf8
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\'' ESCAPED BY ''
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,@q, ...,  `coln`)
  SET `col4` = CONVERT(CONVERT(@q USING utf8mb4) USING utf8);
```

Does anybody see a problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

In order to store Emoji, you *must* use utf8mb4, not utf8 throughout.

A shortcut (perhaps) for the 191 index issue is to upgrade to 5.7.  There, you can keep 255 *and* have indexes.

Only certain columns will be holding Emoji, correct?  Convert just those columns.  (It is OK for different columns in the same table to have different charset and/or collation.)

Comment: The column holding text that is getting the Emoji characters is VARCHAR(255) and it is indexed.  So, I cannot convert it to utf8mb4 without converting to VARCHAR(191).  And I don't want to store the Emoji. I'm looking for a way to throw them out or replace in the LOAD command.